# How quickly does the water increases in the tank reaches the water level is 1m?

Tags: calculus

I have a body with the following parameters:

$y = 0, y = \sqrt{x − 1}, y = 2$ and $x = 0$

On the y-axis. And it is rotated

The question states: The body is a water tank with the height of 2m that is being filled with water at a constant speed of $\frac{1}{2}m^3/min$. How quickly does the water increases in the tank reaches the water level is 1m?

Comment: Does the problem statement say the region bounded by those four equations is rotated around the $y$ axis in order to form the tank? If so, why are you subtracting those two formulas to get $A(x)$? Where did the $25$ come from? Note that if the water level has only reached $y = 1,$ and the problem is asking about an instantaneous rate of change at that time, then the shape of the tank near the top is irrelevant, and so is the volume (below, above, or combined); all that matters is how much water it takes to get a small increase in water level at this particular level  of the tank.

Comment: To get $\sqrt{x-1}$ you can write `$\sqrt{x-1}$`.

Comment: Yes, it is rotated. I will add that detail now.

Comment: I erased what I did

Comment: The usual phrasing is "rotated round the $y$-axis" (or "around the $x$-axis"; either of these can occur, which is why you should always be very explicit about it using words like these). And it is better to show some work, even if it is wrong, explaining what you think each step means and why you did it, rather than show no effort at all. The explanation is as important as the formulas; that's the part that was missing from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous problems of this kind on this site copied from various
exercises in homework or textbooks, describing a tank of some particular shape,
saying that water enters the tank at a certain rate of volume per unit time,
and asking how fast the water level in the tank is increasing when the
water is at a certain level in the tank.

The "obvious" way to work these problems is to compute the volume of the water as a function of the level it has reached, then differentiate this volume relative to the variable that tells the level of the water. Using this derivative, $dV/dh,$
and the given inflow of water, $dV/dt,$ you can easily compute $dh/dt,$
which is what you were asked to compute.

The trick is to understand that in any problem of this kind,
$$V(h) = \int_{h_0}^h A(\eta) d\eta,$$ where $V(h)$ is the volume of water when the level is $h,$ where $A(\eta)$ is the surface area of the top of the water when the level is $\eta,$ and where $h_0$ is the level at the bottom of the tank.
(We usually set things up so that $h_0 = 0,$ but as I'm about to show, this is generally irrelevant.)

Applying the fundamental theorem of calculus,
we can conclude that $$\frac{d}{dh} V(h) = A(h).$$
It's often harder to compute $V(h)$ than $A(h)$--in this case you have to compute $A(h)$ and *then* integrate it in order to get $V(h)$--and on top of that the "obvious" method then forces you to differentiate $V(h)$.
So you integrate $A(h)$ and then differentiate the result, getting back $A(h)$;
what a waste of effort!

In the easy approach, we just use the fact that $dV/dh = A(h),$ compute $A(h),$ and get a simple answer like Phil H's.

Comment: That's.. What I was trying to get

Answer (score 1):

Solving for x, the equation $y = \sqrt{x - 1}$ at y = 1, gives x = 2. At $1$m depth the surface area of the water is $\pi(2)^2 = 4\pi\ m^2$. Hence the rate of  the level rising in the tank is $\frac{0.5}{4\pi} = .0397887$ m/min.

I may get down votes for this solution as it bypasses calculus. But I suggest you pursue the calculus method to help with your studies. Keep this solution in mind when looking for a faster method. That is, tank filling and balloon inflation rates can be determined by dividing the rate of filling by the surface area at a specified fluid level or inflation size.

This is the calculus method:

Because our volume is obtained by revolving $y = \sqrt{x-1}$ around the $y$ axis, the equation needs to be transformed to $x = y^2 + 1$.

$V = \int_0^y \pi\cdot (y^2 + 1)^2 dy$

$\frac{dV}{dy} = \pi\cdot (y^2 + 1)^2$

$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{dV}{dy} \cdot \frac{dy}{dt}$

When $y = 1$

$0.5 = \pi\cdot (1^2 + 1)^2\cdot \frac{dy}{dt}$

$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{0.5}{4\pi} = .0397887$ m/min